# Symfony2 is calling unknown bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed a new bundle using composer
`php bin/console generate:bundle` and I name it `TestBundle` (Just to get familiar with the commands), after that I deleted it by following theses steps:

1. remove it from AppKernel.php
2. remove it's route from app/config/routing.yml
3. and finally I deleted the related folder that contains the bundle

Now each time I open my app symfony shows me this error:

```
Bundle "TestBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file? in @TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp\www\symfony1\app/config\config.yml"). Make sure the "TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" is not empty.
```

How symfony keeps shwoing me errors about a bundle that does not exist ?!

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I would recommend you to simply search your project for `TestBundle`.
Every modern IDE is able to automatically search through all files

Comment: @BenHillier I tried it but it's not working since there is an error in the project

Comment: @EmanuelOster and that's what is driving me crazy because I searched for it in the whole project but I can't find it.

Comment: It looks like you have `@TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` in the list of imports at the top of your `app/config/config.yml` file.

Comment: The Symfony purists won't like me for this, but sometimes I've found it necessary to clear the cache forcibly with `rm -Rf var/cache/dev/* && rm -Rf var/cache/prod/*`

Comment: @qooplmao man thank you so much this resolved the problem, thnx again for your time.

Comment: Please check `AppKernel.php` & `routing.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @qooplmao said, when you install a bundle through the command line it adds the bundle class name to the `AppKernel.php` and routing values to the `routing.yml` in addition to that it imports the services.yml file from the newly generated bundle into the global `config.yml` under `app/config` you need to remove that import statement.